# IE 9 Checkbox Sizing

Tags: css, html, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

IE9 render checkboxes all stretched and ALL other browsers keep the size of the checkbox but expand a click able invisible area.

Can this behavior be disabled in IE9, via css, without changing the behavior of other browser (invisible area)?

This seems to be impossible to have the normal checkbox. Even by selecting other compatibility mode.

I have Windows Vista SP2, 64bits, IE 9.0.8112.16421. Tested on 2 computers with about the same configuration.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <title>IE IS GREAT?</title>
    <style>
    body 
    {
    }

    #test_checkbox
    {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="test_box">
        <input type="checkbox" id="test_checkbox" />
    </div>
  </body>   
</html>
```

Comment: Code sample? What document mode is your document in?  (See the F12 developer tools)

Comment: I had setup a test page here: http://froyo.tv/test/index_checkbox.php

Comment: This seems to be impossible to have the normal checkbox. Even by selecting other compatibility mode.

Comment: @user457015: I went to your test page, and my IE9 shows it like other browsers: original size with a large invisible hit area.

Comment: @BoltClock I have Windows Vista SP2, 64bits, IE 9.0.8112.16421. Tested on 2 computers with about the same configuration.

Comment: @user457015, setting up a test page is all well and good, but when your test page comes back down, no one will be able to learn from your example. The value of SO is in large part because both questions _and_ answers are here; but with only answers, it'll be hard to get much value. :) So please paste code appropriate to your problem.

Comment: @user457015, can you style the `test_box` instead of the `test_checkbox`?

Comment: @sarnold: than It will not answer my question, without using JavaScript, to click the invisible area?!

Comment: IE9 renders it the same as Firefox for me too.. But isn't it sad that browsers are unable to actually make the box bigger? Isn't that was actually should happen instead of just a bigger bounding box? -- I hate standard form fields..

Comment: @poke, what version of Windows you have?

Comment: what about http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/ ?

Comment: @user457015: tested it on two computers now; Win7x64 and Win7x86.

Comment: @JackLeo, Someother with IE9 seems to not have the problem, so... still looking to know, what is going on. And IE9 compatibility mode does not, show the checkbox normal, here.

Comment: Firefox 3.5 running on Debian is unable to expand a clickable area.

Comment: This appears to work fine on Win7; I don't have a Vista box handy to look at.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a label? That will allow you to expand the clickable area:

```
<label for="test_checkbox" style="display: block; width: 300px; height: 300px;">
   <input type="checkbox" id="test_checkbox" />
</label>
```

---

**EDIT:** Example centered:

```
<label for="test_checkbox" style="display: block;">
   <input type="checkbox" id="test_checkbox" style="margin: 150px;" />
</label>
```

Comment: IE9 is actually doing something right in terms of performing what it is instructed to do in this case... stick the checkbox inside a label and apply dimensions to that label.

Comment: Maybe IE9 is right, but since all others are doing differently it is wrong!

Comment: With this solution the checkbox is not vertically centered for the height.

Comment: @user457015: There are plenty of ways to center elements. Edited for an example.